# What is the preferred way to define an array in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What is the preferred way to define an array in a mongoose Schema ?

Here are the two I found, but I am unable to decide which one is the best to use.

```
var DocumentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  wayOne: [
    {
      type: String
    }
  ],

  wayTwo: {
    type: [String]
  },
});
```

I would prefer the second way, because I would be able to do something like

```
wayTwo: {
  type: [String],
  enum: ['one', 'two', 'three'],
  default: []
}
```

and I don't know how to do this with the first way.

In short, I am looking at some old code I didn't write, and saw the two ways in use, so I was wondering I there was something to note about one of the way, or if it would be safe to standardize in converting all to the best way.

Comment: `wayOne: []` works too.

Comment: I know, but note it will create a Mixed type and not explicitly a String type

Comment: I'd use number one but is a subjective opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what sort of data you'll have in the array. The answer is subjective of course, because all of the ways you mention work. Which one is best, however, depends on the kind of data/structure you'll need for your model. Do you know the answer to that yet? Maybe with more specifics we can find a better/focused answer for you, but even then, it's still subjective because they all work.

**edit**
I would use the first one by the way.

Comment: If anyone come to this thinking, know that the best way seems to be purely subjective, and you can choose the one that you like the most.